# AngularJS - Difference in passing variables to functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

One method passes an array, the other a function; is there a difference between the two? Should one be used over the other depending on the situation? What's the point in naming all the variables twice?

Is "variable" the correct term for what's being passed in, or is there a more specific term for these particular types of variables in AngularJS?

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
```

vs

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in the array if you want to minify your code before deploying to production.

Because minify changes the name of your parameters, and angular Dependency Injection relies on parameter names, if they get minified (from '$routeProvider' to 'a') it wouldn't recognize it, that's why you add the Array, because minification doesn't change strings.

They both do the same basically, if you don't need minification don't use the array way, but usually you do...

About the "variable" term, it's more of an "Injectable" than a variable... because it is something the DI replace with a singleton, which can be a function or an object or a string etc...